# How to Select table from csv file in clickhouse with its column name as header

Tags: csv, clickhouse

I try to select a csv file using clickhouse but my column header name its not include and instead it become row number 1, like this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLGzd.png)

```
this is my code :
SELECT 
    *
    FROM file(
        'trx_okt_2022.csv'
    )
```

```
what can i add so it can read its header column name
```

Comment: i try adding Format CSV.. and result with :

Code: 27. DB::ParsingException: Cannot parse input: expected ',' before: \argo,C,,11,1,1,12359053\r\n2022-10-01,1,988,PT Garuda': 
Row 1:
Column 0,   name: date,          type: Date,   parsed text: "date,Cli"
ERROR: garbage after Date: "entId,Pref"
ERROR: Date must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.
: While executing CSVRowInputFormat: While executing File: (in file/uri /var/lib/clickhouse/user_files/trx_okt_2022.csv): (at row 1)
. (CANNOT_PARSE_INPUT_ASSERTION_FAILED)

Answer (score 1):

[CSVWithNames](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#csvwithnames) includes the first line as a header for columns.

The way to read from it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM file('trx_okt_2022.csv', 'CSVWithNames');
```